# 294 плановые путёвки или 294 плановых путевок?

Tags: согласование

«...то для отдыха в нём в 2017 году выделено 294 плановые путёвки». Верно согласование с путевками? Или 294 плановых путевок?

Answer (score 4):

1) **Без определения:** Выделено 4 путевки, 294 путевки - здесь используется существительное **в форме ед. числа для числительных "два, три, четыре"** и составных числительных на "два, три, четыре".

2) **Выбираем форму определения**: 4 плановых путевки или 4 плановые путевки? Розенталь **рекомендует** "4 плановые путевки", так как формы "путевки" (И.п. мн.число) и "нет путевки" (Р.р. ед.ч.) совпадают.

[§193. Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_03)

3) **Вывод: верен вариант 294 плановые путевки.**

4) **А откуда "294 плановых путевок"?** Здесь используется форма мн. числа "плановых", а после  нее ставится **по принципу согласования** форма мн. числа существительного, но существительное на 2, 3, 4 согласуется с формой **ед. числа** существительного, поэтому этот вариант **неверен** (хотя на слух ошибка не очень заметна).

Comment: Ну ведь формы "путевки" (И.п. мн.число) и "нет путевки" (Р.р. ед.ч.) совпадают не только орфографически, но и в ударении. В справочнике же говорится, что родительный рекомендуется в том случае, если ударение в падежах отличается.

Comment: Ср.: Разыграны три золотые медали. – Разыграно три золотых медали.  Здесь тоже падежи совпадают, но возможны два варианта.

Comment: Розенталь рассматривает влияние различных факторов. если падежные формы совпадают, то рекомендуется И.п.В нашем случае лучше выбрать вариант "выделенЫ 294 плановые путёвки", Вариант "РазыгранО три золотых медали". приводится  как возможный при ед. числе сказуемого.  Но вот для СОСТАВНОГО числительного  он на слух  кажется неверным "выделено 294 плановых путёвки".  Поэтому "путевки" заменяют на "путевок",  а это грамматически неверно.

Comment: Почему же, с справочнике написано: ***(а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры)***. Да, вы правы, при ед.ч. сказуемого.Но почему вы настаиваете только на одном варианте: если изменить число сказуемого, возможен и другой вариант.

Comment: У автора как раз ед. ч. А в ед.ч. правильно: плановых, а не плановые.

Comment: А автора -  "плановых ПУТЕВОК", а это уже неправильно. Или вы считаете "путевок" - это правильно?

Comment: Не путевок, а путевки. Путевок,конечно,неправильно.

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от формы сказуемого, возможны оба варианта:

> Выделен**ы** 294 планов**ые** путёвки; выделен**о** 294 планов**ых** путёвки..

Вот что говорится в справочнике по литературной правке (Розенталь. Д.Э.).

При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных два, три, четыре (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола. Например: ...Офицеры ели жадно, без разговоров, наверстывали за два потерянных в боях дня (Шолохов); Два крайних окна в первом этаже закрыты изнутри газетными листами... (А.Н. Толстой).

2. При существительных **женского рода** в указанных условиях определение чаще ставится **в форме именительного падежа** (или совпадающего с ним винительного при неодушевленных существительных) множественного числа.

   > Например: **две большие комнаты выходили окнами в сад; купила четыре фарфоровые чашки; на изгороди из трех жердей сидели три женские фигуры (А.Н. Толстой);** **По этим дорогам двигаются две большие колонны немцев (М. Бубеннов).**

На выбор формы определения **может оказать влияние форма сказуемого;**

ср.: Разыгран**ы** три золотые медали. – Разыгран**о** три золотых медали.

Comment: Серж, а почему у вас для случая глагола с окончанием на -о "плановых путёвок" от "золотых медали" отличаются?

Comment: @ Alex_ander, если честно, не понял: что отличается и чем отличается?

Comment: 294... путёвок, но 3 медали (второе сомнений не вызывает).

Comment: А,вы про "путевок"? Скопировал, и даже не заметил, что там написано "путевки", а не путевок. Прочитал ответ Sibylla, увидел ошибку.

Comment: Теперь всё на своих местах :)

Comment: Спасибо, что заметили. :)

Answer (score 1):

Для нашего случая акцента на количестве (выделен**о** столько-то таких-то предметов) возьмём более очевидный пример и посмотрим, что с чем согласовано:

> Было проколот**о** 294 зелён**ых** шарик**а**.

Ясно, что не "294... шариков" (явное рассогласование *с числительным*) и не "проколото... зелёные шарики" (явное рассогласование *с глаголом*). Возвращаемся к нашим "плановым путёвкам", сохранив связи согласования по падежам:

> Выделен**о** 294 планов**ых** путёвк**и**.

При акценте на сами путёвки (это стилистически хуже с большими числами) грамматически возможен вариант:

> Выделен**ы** 294 планов**ые** путёвк**и**.